# Group by 2 keys with only month in second key

Tags: python, postgresql, date, group-by, grouping

I am trying to do a group by 2 keys in my list of dict the second key being datetime.date. I need to group by nick_name and by month and do a couple of sums, conditional sums etc.

In SQL it would be something like

```
select 
    rw_worker_nick
    ,date_trunc( 'month', rw_date ) as month
    ,sum(rw_end - rw_start)  as work_time
from 
results_woshi  
where 
rw_script = 93 
group by
  rw_worker_nick
 ,date_trunc( 'month', rw_date ) 
 order by month
```

keys have the same names as db columns

there are just some more where conditions which I think will be easier to do in python than on db level

this is my code so far but I do not know how to group by month

```
grouper = itemgetter("rw_worker_nick", "rw_date")
result = []

from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint



for key, grp in groupby(sorted(summary, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["rw_worker_nick", "rw_date"], key))
    result.append(temp_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than relying upon `itemgetter`, write your own key function which ignores the day in the date:

```
grouper = lambda x: (x["rw_worker_nick"], x["rw_date"].replace(day=1))
```

This shifts every date to the first of its month. If you want to group the items from the same month in different years, you can use `x["rw_date"].month` instead of the `replace` call.